# How to fix the tainted source of data in Coverity issue

Tags: python, coverity

Trying to read the URL from json file which in Coverity report shows as taint (untrusted source of data). And the issue is called as URL Manipulation where I used the URL attribute from json.
Can anyone suggest wasys to mitigate the URL Manipulation error in Coverity report.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It means you need to parse/validate the url string.
You can do this in a number of ways - either with your own regex, or with purpose-built libraries ([urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html), [validators](https://pypi.org/project/validators/)).
For example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

URL_TO_TEST = "https:/www.google.com"
result = urlparse(URL_TO_TEST)
if (result.scheme and result.netloc) is False:
    raise ValueError("Invalid url string")

print(f"url: '{URL_TO_TEST}' is valid")
```

The [Snyk page for the same type of issue](https://snyk.io/blog/secure-python-url-validation/) provides some good info.